# Prove a sequence is a divisibility sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Sequence: $a_n=2^n-1$

I want to prove that $a_m|a_n$ whenever $m|n$.

I started by approaching with induction, base/trivial cases being $m=n$, $n=0$, and $m=1$, but I'm not sure where to go from there or if there is a more straightforward method.

Note:

$m|n$ means for some $x$, $mx = n$

$a_m|a_n$ means for some $y$, $a_my=a_n$

Other similar questions appeal to laws beyond basic arithmetic and the definitions of divisibility and the sequence.

Comment: Use the fact that $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \ldots + b^{n-1})$

Answer (score 0):

If $m | n$ then
$n = km$
so

$\begin{array}\\
2^n-1
&=2^{km}-1\\
&=(2^{m})^k-1\\
&=(2^m-1)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}2^{jm}\\
\end{array}
$